# Power BI - DAX - Cannot be Converted to a Scalar Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I think there's nothing wrong with this, but PBI disagrees:

**The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.**

I want this to do more, but I have it stripped down to the bare minimum requirements for troubleshooting. I've tried all kinds of tricks, but nothing seems to be working.

```
Summarize = SUMMARIZE(
    MailboxStatisticsHistorical,
    MailboxStatisticsHistorical[Date],
    "Distinct", DISTINCTCOUNT(MailboxStatisticsHistorical[Identity])
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMMARIZE returns a calculated table. You can't assign it to a measure. (Measures expect scalar results.) Use the Calculated Table UI instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I haven't played with this feature. This is nice, thanks.